# How to handle double click scenario for ajax in spring mvc - Can we make using token synchronization pettern here in some way

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

How to handle double click scenario for ajax in spring mvc - Can we make use of token synchronization pettern here in some way

Comment: Could you provide some detail about your specific problem?

Comment: Some context as to what you are trying to do would help us help you.